# Error message says "I can't find file tikzlibraryanimations.code.tex"

Tags: texstudio, miktex2.9, miktex-update, tikzlibrary

My TeXstudio editor is doing well. But whenever I need to use the package `\usetikzlibrary{}`,  get an error message `I can't find file "tikzlibraryanimations.code.tex"`.

I have tried to update MikTeX through the local repository `...MikTeX\tm\package`, but it says all packages are up-to-date.

How do I get rid of such an error? Which file or package should I download into my "local repository folder"?